# Initialization of vector with stream iterators

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

I'm trying to familiarize myself with std streams :).
And I whant to initialize vector from stream, using std::istreambuf_iterator. Consider we have some stream:

```
std::string str("Bla-bla bla-bla-bla");
std::stringstream str_s(str);
```

When I try to initialize vector like this:

```
std::vector<char> vec(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(str_s), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

VC compiler doesn't treat `vec` as an object of class `std::vector<char>`. So if I write:

```
vec.size()
```

I`ll get compilation error. Something like: *"Expression to the left of .size must be an object of class/struct etc.*
But if I add extra parentheses around first parameter to vector initialization. Like this:

```
std::vector<char> vec1((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(str_s)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Everything goes OK.
Why? What the difference?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse